# How to bypass a low priority line of code havin fatal error?

Tags: php

Example :

Say I have a logging class, and I use a global variable instance of it throughout the code.

```
$logger = new Logger();

function correctWorking()
{
   global $logger;
   $logger->log("this is correct");
}

function failing()
{
   $logger->log("this is fatal error");  /* here fatal error comes, :  Call to a member  
                                          function log() on a non-object in ...
                                         */
   moreImportantWork();
}
```

Please do not suggest better coding practices,I am working on them.
My main curiousity is, how can I bypass the fatal error line, if the error occurs,
as logging is not as important as keeping the app running.

Comment: How about `$this->log("Error") = new logger();`

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Yes,that is the way to go,but I wanted to know a bypassing mechanism

Comment: @DhruvPathak: There isn't one, fortunately. Fix the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

You can suppress the error output like `@$logger->log("this is fatal error");` but:

- This is sloppy coding;
- The script still terminates.

Instead, fix the fatal error.

Comment: You could suggest a way to handle this kind of problem like creating a `function log()` or checking if `$logger` is an object of instance `Logger`

Comment: @Alfwed: It would be irresponsible of me to lead the OP down that path.

Comment: The OP isn't concerned about good practices and is looking for a quick fix.

Comment: @Alfwed: I couldn't care less.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with fatal errors. On lower level errors you could write your own error_handler which creates an exception from them. Then you can use `try { ... } catch { /* do nothing here */ }` to avoid the termination of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `global $logger;` in the `failing()` function, that appears to be your problem.

Comment: yes Nexerus, but my question is "HOW TO BYPASS THAT ERROR?" with minimal changes in code.

Comment: Turn off PHP's error reporting, problem solved. But why bypass it? if your code is throwing errors it's clearly poorly written making it unstable and bad, very very _bad_.

Comment: its primarily to deal with external api/library dependencies and to for learning purpose.

Comment: @DhruvPathak: Learning by attempting to ignore "fatal" errors is ridiculous.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal : "Learning" here meant "knowing if something like that exists". I agree with your viewpoint that this would be a bad practice and should not be followed,not "learned" as you perceived it.

Comment: @DhruvPathak: `s/if/whether/`

Answer (score -2):

If i understand you correct you want to skip errors in your code and go on executing the script?
You can use the @ operator to supress fatal errors

```
@$logger->log("this is fatal error");
```

for more examples http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Yes, similar to what I am looking for. Let me try it and get back.

Comment: -1: [Oh, really?](http://codepad.org/IChXti0y) - [moving it](http://codepad.org/o0Isk3La) makes the _message_ suppression work, but the script still terminates. You can't "ignore" fatal errors.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal , Yes, only message is suppressed.

Comment: @DhruvPathak: As I just demonstrated with a live example.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal you are right and iam aware that this is bad practice, but the user asked for a quick way. Fatal Errors in general cant be supressed but i thought the user refering to an 'error'.

Comment: @Michele: The OP clearly talks about "keeping the app running"

Comment: @Michele: Also did you notice my first link? Your script example is _invalid code_.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal yeah i notice your link, i edited my answer or should i delete it?

Comment: @Michele: It's better now, but it still says that you can "go on executing the script", which is _not what that code does_.